# Obtain localized file size in Mac OS X

Tags: cocoa, macos, localization

I got a file size in byte in a `(unsigned long long)` variable. Is there a standard way to convert it to a string, with localized units?

I am aware of those kind of solutions :

```
NSString * stringFromFileSize( FileSize theSize )
{
    float floatSize = theSize;
    if (theSize<1023)
        return ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i bytes",theSize]);
    floatSize = floatSize / 1024;
    if (floatSize<1023)
        return ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.1f KB",floatSize]);
    floatSize = floatSize / 1024;
    if (floatSize<1023)
        return ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.1f MB",floatSize]);
    floatSize = floatSize / 1024;

    return([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.1f GB",floatSize]);
}
```

But it doesn't work in French, where 'octet' is used instead of bytes (and all B from the units have to be replaced by an 'o'). I've searched around `CFLocalGetValue`, looked at all formatting methods I know about without any success, so is there any hidden method/function to help me? I can manage to build something by hand, but I would prefere avoiding it.

Comment: Note that the Finder in Mac OS X 10.6 reports file sizes in 1000-based units (although 10.5 and before used 1024-based units).  Depending on the application, you might want to be consistent with that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [NSLocalizedString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html). You can add an entry to your French localization (in Localizable.strings):

```
"bytes" = "octets";
"KB" = "Ko";
"MB" = "Mo";
"GB" = "Go";
```

Then use:

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i %@", theSize, NSLocalizedString(@"bytes", nil)];
```

To more specifically answer the question, I'm not aware of any Cocoa function for handling these conversions.

Comment: That's what I was planning to do if I didn't found a 'standard' way to do it. Finder do it with no problem, it's weird the platform doesn't give it for free like for the dates :-/

Comment: The Finder does the same thing. You can find a lot of similar strings in Apple frameworks' .lproj folders.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who's facing the same problem: there is a handy `NSByteCountFormatter` class, which provides localization. Looks like it wasn't around when the question was asked. It works since OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion.